# getSpreadsheetTimeZone() returns wrong Time Zone

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone

I have a G Sheet script which is executed form Add-ons -> 'Add-on name -> 'do stuff'

During the add-on execution, I have to generate a date in user's time zone or at least in a spreadsheet time zone. I'm doing the following:

```
 var timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
 var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, 'yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss z');
```

Problem I have, that `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` gives me a wrong time zone than it's set in my spreadsheet settings.

Here is the flow. I create a new spreadsheet, by default, it's in *Central European Time (CET)* I run my add-on which should execute the above code and insert a date in the spreadsheet. However, I get the date in *Pacific Standard Time (PST)*. When I go to the Spreadsheet settings and change the time zone and re-run my add-on I get exactly right time zone which is in the settings.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Notes:

- My add-on published privately.
- `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` - returns exactly *America/Los_Angeles* value in the case of *PST*

Comment: Did you check the time zone in the script editor (File > Project properties) ?

Comment: Yes, It's set to CET.

Comment: Maybe try var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

Comment: Did that, It always returns me CTE which is set in the (File > Project properties) and doesn't take into account the time zone in the spreadsheet settings.

Comment: It could be a bug.  If it's a bug, then you should report it on the issue tracker.  [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)  You'll need to be able to explain the steps that can consistently reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @SandyGood It seems like a bug to me. I'll report an issue.